# How to find Shadow(Hidden) module of a program?

Tags: c++, dll, module

I have a function that iterates through modules and compares module size to main module and module address != main module address then its assuming that its shadow module address but its not correct way to do it I guess because When I uninject my dll and try to inject and retrieve shadow module address again this function fails cannot find shadow module because I think shadow module size changes.I tried to log main module size its same.

```
[2023-01-22 13:56:32]   ----------------- MFX.dll injected in to the League process ----------------- 
[2023-01-22 13:56:32]  MinHook Initalized!... 
[2023-01-22 13:56:32]  WndProc Hook... 
[2023-01-22 13:56:32]  MAIN MODULE SIZE 
[2023-01-22 13:56:32]  52838400[2023-01-22 13:56:32]  
[2023-01-22 14:20:39]   ----------------- MFX.dll injected in to the League process -----------------
```

This is the function I'm using for retrieve shadow module address.

```
bool MEM::GetShadowModule(std::uintptr_t& base_address)
{
    /* The `shadow module` has the same size as the `league` module, but has a different base */
    /* Get base address of `League of Legends.exe` */

    /* Check if `League of Legends.exe` is loaded */
    if (!LeagueBase)
        return false;

    /* Get Module information */
    MODULEINFO module_info = { 0 };
    if (!GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), (HMODULE)LeagueBase, &module_info, sizeof(MODULEINFO)))
        return false;

    /* Get module size */
    std::uintptr_t module_size = (std::uintptr_t)module_info.SizeOfImage;

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memory_info = { 0 };
    /* Start at end of league base */
    std::uintptr_t current_address = LeagueBase + module_size;

    /* Loop until we find the shadow module */
    while (VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)current_address, &memory_info, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32)))
    {

        /* Check if the size is the same as the league module */
        if (memory_info.RegionSize == module_size && memory_info.BaseAddress != (LPVOID)LeagueBase)
        {
            /*We found shadow module base address Set the base address*/
            base_address = current_address;
            return true;
        }

        /* Move to the next region */
        current_address += memory_info.RegionSize;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm just making some memory allocations/memcpy like that in my DLL.I suspect these are changing shadow module size & sinking my function ?

```
    auto GateWay = VirtualAlloc(NULL, ByteSize + 5, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,       //Create a Gateway
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(GateWay, (PVOID)HookAddress, ByteSize);                                // Copy Original Bytes to GateWay
```

I'm looking for a better way to find shadow module address rather than comparing its size.If it's a duplicate question then I'm sorry.I couldn't find any similiar question regarding shadow module.